# Refresh Git repo fork with a pending PR

Tags: git, pull-request, git-fork

I have been contributing to an open-source project hosted in a GitHub repo. I started by forking the project into my own GutHub account and have had several pull requests (PRs) accepted.

I now find myself in a predicament where I have a PR awaiting acceptance/rejection and my code base is well out of date. I have another candidate fix but would feel happier working from the latest code base to reduce the potential for merge conflicts. How can I refresh my code base, without losing the changes in my outstanding PR, so I can submit another PR?

Comment: I suggest merging the main branch into yours, depending on your last changes and how old your branch is there may be conficts so you'll have to solve them. By doing this it's like you are assuming your changes will be accepted and you are working from the point after.